# My login page username text and password text position are different

Tags: android, authentication, android-layout

im new to android and java, this is my 1st building login page for my project app, confuse with android studio layout,

My login page username text and password text position are different! anyone have any suggestion for my coding?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/eschool"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="PLT MUAR 行政系统"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="126dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="用户名 UserID:"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_column">
```

this my username text part:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="text|textUri"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

This my password part below:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="密码 Password:"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="124dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/login_column"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VebP.png)

any better suggestion for my front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because for password you use TextInputLayout with TextInputEditText and for username you use EditText, for username instead EditText use TextInputLayout with TextInputEditText as in password example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_column"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```